# Error while executing python code

Tags: python-2.7, lua, tshark

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# coding: utf-8
import sys

import os

import time

b = 'sudo tshark -i eth0 -R “tcp contains “attack”” -T fields -e ip.src -a duration:60>output.txt'

a = os.popen(b)

time.sleep(32)

f = open('output.txt','r')

text = 'IP address of attacker is'

print (text), f.read()

f.close
```

I am trying to execute this code to capture packets using tshark but i am getting this error:

```
tshark: "�" was unexpected in this context.
```

Please help me why that error is caused, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The error message is because `tshark` tries to disable some dangerous functions in Lua like `dofile`.

If you don't need Lua in tshark, you can disable Lua support: edit `init.lua`, change `disable_lua = false` to `disable_lua = true`.

If you need Lua support, read [Platform-Specific information about capture privileges](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/CapturePrivileges), see how to capture packets without root rivilege.

Comment: I changed the disable_lua = true in init.lua but still im getting the error:


tshark: "�" was unexpected in this context.


Please help me.